# Sharepoint - Set site category through code

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to change the site category of a site, or add it in the moment of creation through code?

Thanks,
David Esteves

Comment: It's best if you edit your question and add more information about what exactly you are speaking about. In particular: Where does that category appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no "category" on a site. If you refer to the "site directory" (where you can list your various sites beneath some categories), that is actually implemented as yet another SharePoint site using lists, and you should be able to change the category of an entry simply by changing the corresponding list item in the directory.